# str_replace com explode php

Tags: php

```
> A sua viagem  Ref. reserva:   5SPGW9  Check My Trip

    Data de emissão:    06 Novembro 2015    
 .
 .
Viajante    Mrs Ana Paula Monteiro Malfati      Agência INTERCAMBIO OPERADORA DE PROGRAMAS EDUC
Rua Dos Tres Irmaos, 625
Vila Progredior  Cep:05615-190
SAO PAULO
Telefone    (11) 3149-8199
Fax (11) 3149-8199
E-mail  intercambio@intercambioglobal.com.br



 .


 .
  Sexta-feira 29 Janeiro 2016
```

Estou tentado separar este texto em 3 blocos, mas ele não está aceitando os comandos. Eu primeiro troco os pontos por `" "` e depois dou explode nas quebras de linhas, mas não funciona.

```
$dados = str_replace(".", " ", $dados);
$dados = explode("\n\n", $dados);
```

`$dados` é onde armazeno este texto.

Answer (score 1):

Primeira coisa, utilizar apenas um ponto '.' vai apresentar vários conflitos visto no seu texto tem `[Ref.] [.com.br]` ele iria acabar fazendo a substituição em um lugar errado.

Como você quer apenas substituir os pontos por espaços e criar três blocos você pode poderia resolver assim:

```
$foo = 'A sua viagem  Ref reserva:   5SPGW9  Check My Trip
        Data de emissão:    06 Novembro 2015
      ..
      Viajante Mrs Ana Paula Monteiro Malfati
      Agência INTERCAMBIO OPERADORA DE PROGRAMAS EDUC
      Rua Dos Tres Irmaos, 625
      Vila Progredior  Cep:05615-190
      SAO PAULO
      Telefone    (11) 3149-8199
      Fax (11) 3149-8199
      E-mail  intercambio@intercambioglobal.com.br
      ..
      Sexta-feira 29 Janeiro 2016';

$blocos = explode("..", $foo);
echo $blocos[0];
echo $blocos[1];
echo $blocos[2];
```

Adicionei dois pontos seguidos para evitar o conflito.

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/OXYdQU)

Comment: o problema é que esse texto vem nesse formato, então, eu preciso tratá-lo desse jeito.
E a quebra de linha dele vem como "."

Comment: Por que eu ganhei -1 ?

Comment: não fui eu fera..

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro: é interessante retirar as quebras de linhas (como é substituída por dois pontos consecutivos usaremos isso a nosso favor).

Segundo: vamos usar o explode para separar nosso array onde estão as quebras de linhas, gerando um array com as três partes, que fica desta forma:

```
Array
(
    [0] => > A sua viagem Ref. reserva: 5SPGW9 Check My Trip Data de emissão: 06 Novembro 2015
    [1] => Viajante Mrs Ana Paula Monteiro Malfati Agência INTERCAMBIO OPERADORA DE PROGRAMAS EDUC Rua Dos Tres Irmaos, 625 Vila Progredior Cep:05615-190 SAO PAULO Telefone (11) 3149-8199 Fax (11) 3149-8199 E-mail intercambio@intercambioglobal.com.br
    [2] => Sexta-feira 29 Janeiro 2016 
)
```

Terceiro: Utilizamos um strpos para retirar parte da frase, com o início começando do 3 caractere(removendo caracteres não desejados) até o palavra 'Trip'.

Quarto: utilizamos novamente o strpos + substring para retirar somente o texto da data de emissão.

Quinto: capturamos a mensagem que está na segunda linha do array do explode que fizemos.

Sexto: capturamos a data que está no final do array do explode que fizemos.

Sétimo: exibimos os dados.

```
<?php
// Texto completo
$texto = "> A sua viagem  Ref. reserva:   5SPGW9  Check My Trip

    Data de emissão:    06 Novembro 2015    
 .
 .
Viajante    Mrs Ana Paula Monteiro Malfati      Agência INTERCAMBIO OPERADORA DE PROGRAMAS EDUC
Rua Dos Tres Irmaos, 625
Vila Progredior  Cep:05615-190
SAO PAULO
Telefone    (11) 3149-8199
Fax (11) 3149-8199
E-mail  intercambio@intercambioglobal.com.br



 .


 .
  Sexta-feira 29 Janeiro 2016   ";

// Texto recebido sem quebras de linha
$string = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $texto);
// Separa o texto em três partes
$ex = explode(" . . ", $string);
// Utilizamos o strpos para capturar do terceiro caractere (ou seja eliminamos o espaço o sinal de maior e mais um espaço do início) até a palavra Trip.  Assim capturamos o idReserva
$str_pos2 =  strpos($ex[0], ' Data de emissão:');
$txt_idReserva = substr($ex[0], 2, $str_pos2 -1);
// Utilizamos o strpos para capturar o que vem depois da palavra 'Trip' + espaço. Ou seja capturamos a data de emissão
$str_pos = strpos($ex[0], 'Trip ');
$txt_dtEmissao  = substr($ex[0], $str_pos + strlen('Trip '), strlen($ex[0]));
// Pegamos a mensagem
$txt_msg = $ex[1];
// Pegamos a data
$txt_dt = $ex[2];

echo "$txt_idReserva" . "<br>" . $txt_dtEmissao .  "<br>". $txt_msg . "<br>" . $txt_dt;
```

O código acima irá imprimir:

```
A sua viagem Ref. reserva: 5SPGW9 Check My Trip 
Data de emissão: 06 Novembro 2015
Viajante Mrs Ana Paula Monteiro Malfati Agência INTERCAMBIO OPERADORA DE PROGRAMAS EDUC Rua Dos Tres Irmaos, 625 Vila Progredior Cep:05615-190 SAO PAULO Telefone (11) 3149-8199 Fax (11) 3149-8199 E-mail intercambio@intercambioglobal.com.br
Sexta-feira 29 Janeiro 2016
```

Você pode utilizar o explode ou outras funções string para separar a terceira parte do texto (chamei a variável de `$txt_msg`) que é a mensagem contendo dados do passageiro.